# Datagrab import, relationshipfield inside grid

Tags: relationships, grid, import, datagrab

I'm trying to achieve an import with datagrab with the following field construction:

A grid, and inside a grid I have a column with a relationship field (and some other normal text field inputs in the other columns).

When I import a csv, it looks like Datagrab doesn't process these relationship fields at all inside a grid. Whereas standalone relationship fields do seem to import fine.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to import a relationship inside a grid or do I actually need to hack Datagrab or create custom extension code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one that really you should direct to the author of Datagrab... it is quite possible though that the add-on does not support the importing of relationships within grids.

The datagrab web site suggests there is a support forum for such requests, but that appears to be offline, so the alternatives to [fill in the contact form](https://brandnewbox.co.uk/contact) or send in an email (address given on contact page).

HTH

> PS - in passing, good practice is to include information in a question
> about the version of EE that you are using, and of any add-on you are
> asking about - to make it easier for people to answer; there are
> significant differences between versions of EE, and in some add-ons
> etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah I tried to ask the Datagrab team directly but after two weeks and several attempts to get a reaction from them was getting no results sadly. So asking it here was my last resort, kind of.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but when Datagrab doesn't support some types of field data I import data into a temporary textarea field or two, then go through entries one by one and update. It doesn't take long to do with a couple of hundred entries, but if you have thousands of entries you might need to set aside a few days!